# What is the difference between Array and WrappedArray in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I'm a bit confused in terms of those 2 collections.

I understand that Scala's Array calls Java API. In such a case, what's the role of a Wrapped Array (and its performance characteritics)?

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/WrappedArray.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`WrappedArray` wraps an `Array` to give it extra functionality.  It also have a bunch of types while array extends only serializable and cloneable, This allows an array to be wrapped so it can be used in places where some generic collection type like `Seq` is required.

Also notable is `ArrayOps` Which is similar to `WrappedArray` in that it enriches an Array with extra operations.  The difference is that Operations in`ArrayOps` return a regular `Array` while operations from `WrappedArray` return a `WrappedArray`

`ArrayOps` has priority over `WrappedArray` so it will be used unless one of the types provided by `WrappedArray` is needed.

Comment: Doc reference for Java?