# cas Exception:scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [D

Tags: scala, apache-spark

throwing ClassCastExpection when applying knn classifier

```
val df = training.map{ r =>
   (Vectors.dense(r.getAs[Array[Double]]("features")),r.getAs[Int]("id"))
  }.toDF("features","id")
```

error appear

```
scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [D
```

I try Seq, WrappedArray but does't work.

Comment: Can you please print training data and schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume the following schema for `training`:

```
id:Integer
features: Array[Double]
```

Try:
`val df = training.map(r => (Vectors.dense(r.getAs[Seq[Double]]("features").toArray),r.getAs[Integer]("id"))).toDF("features","id")`

Datasets internally store `Array` objects are `WrappedArray`, a quick intro of which can be found here.

[Array vs Wrapped array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881942/what-is-the-difference-between-array-and-wrappedarray-in-scala)

So, you should "extract" your `array` of `doubles` by casting it to `Seq[Double]` instead of `Array[Double]`. However, the method `dense` needs `Array[Double]`. So, convert the `Seq[Double]` to `Array[Double]` using the `toArray` method.

```
val training = List((Seq(0.0,0.0),2),(Seq(1.0,1.0),5)).toDF("features","id")
training.show
+----------+---+
|  features| id|
+----------+---+
|[0.0, 0.0]|  2|
|[1.0, 1.0]|  5|
+----------+---+
training: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [features: array<double>, id: int]


val df = training.map(r => (Vectors.dense(r.getAs[Seq[Double]]("training").toArray),r.getAs[Integer]("id"))).toDF("features","id")
df.show

+---------+---+
| features| id|
+---------+---+
|[0.0,0.0]|  2|
|[1.0,1.0]|  5|
+---------+---+
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [features: vector, id: int]
```

Hope this helps.